# cerrar session en mvc 4

Tags: mvc

No puedo cerrar una sesión abierta.

Uso este método pero no FUNCIONA.

```
<a>
href="@Url.Action("CerrarSesion","Home")"> <i class="icon-key"></i> Cerrar Sesión
</a>
```

Acá tengo el controlador.

```
<HttpPost()>
    Function CerrarSesion() As ActionResult 
        If IsNothing(Session) = False Then 
            Session("usuario") = Nothing 
            Session("usu") = Nothing 
            Session.Clear() 
            Session.Abandon() 
        End If 
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut() 
        Return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home") 
    End Function
```

cuando usa esta forma me dice que "no encuentra el recurso".

y acá tengo esta función y la uso en un botón y no me funciona...

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function SessionAbandon() {
        $.ajax({ 
            type: "POST", 
            url: "/Home/CerrarSesion", 
            data: {}, 
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
            dataType: "json", 
            async: true, 
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                alert(textStatus + ": " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText); 
            } 
            }); 
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: `<HttpPost()>` eso está demás en la función si queres usar `@Url.Action`. En ese caso no es necesario hacer un post. Y no está hecho para eso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que funcione `@Url.Action` lo que tenés que hacer es quitar `<HttpPost()>` del controlador.

`@Url.Action` no está diseñado para hacer post y no necesitás hacer post tampoco.

Answer (score 1):

La instruccion `FormsAuthentication.SignOut()` es suficiente para desloguearse, eso lo puedes validar con la variable `context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`. Lo unico que veo raro ahi es que el ajax no te puede redireccionar con un `Return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home")` tendrias que retornar un `HttpStatusCodeResult(401); // Unauthorized` o simplemente asignarlo en el response `Response.StatusCode = 401;` y cacharlo en el success del ajax o configurarlo en el ajax setup:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    statusCode: {
    // unauthorized
    '401': function () {
      window.location.href = action.home.index;
    }
});
```

Comment: gracias tio me sirvió te debo una. solo le quite <HttpPost()> eso al controlador. :)

Comment: @heiner O sea que la respuesta correcta fue la mia jeje ¿la publico?